# i need to update a field in salesforce when someone opens an email sent from marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automation, marketing-cloud-connect, activity

I would like to update a field in salesforce when someone opens an email sent from marketing cloud. I tried to add an engagement split in journey builder but i needed to add a wait time in. Does this mean that it will only asses the open of the email once? If I want something to happen only once the email is opened (in this case notify the sales person in Salesforce) I wondered if this is something that other users have done and how they have done this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible in journey builder as a journey represents the exact path a subscriber goes and isn't suitable for recurring tasks. To accomplish what you like to do you could create a scheduled automation in automation studio that queries the open tracking data view and updates the salesforce records accordingly.

The activities you need for this task are:

- [SQL Query Activity](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/)
- [Script Activity](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/create_a_script_activity/)

**Additional resources:**

- [Data View: Open](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/data_views/data_view_open/)
- [Server-Side JavaScript Syntax Guide](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/)

Comment: @user48743 You are welcome! If so, please mark my answer as accepted, so others can easily see your problem has been resolved. Thank you!